# Save file as .pdf or .doc

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdfmake

I'm using `pdfmake.js`, and I get this when I open in a window:

```
data:application/pdf;base64,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
```

How can I save this pdf and if possible, can I convert or make it into a word document?

Essentially I want the data URI so I can use it with FileSaver.js to download, but I can't figure out where the URI is in the pdfmake.js **[file](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/blob/master/build/pdfmake.js)**.

Comment: Could you please provide the code that generates this message?

In the meantime might I suggest you take a look at the documentation for PDFMake. They have a playground section for trying out code.

http://pdfmake.org/index.html#/gettingstarted

Comment: @PatrickFritch: If someone decodes the code you posted as base64, they will get your PDF. You might want to omit everything after the `base64,` part.

Comment: I want the data URI so I can use it with FileSaver.js to download, but I can't figure out where the URI is in the pdfmake.js file [link](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/blob/master/build/pdfmake.js)

Answer (score 0):

First what you need is to make a BLOB from base64 and then pass it as url to the anchor. In order to convert base64 to Blob take a look here:

[Creating a Blob from a base64 string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript)

then create url from blob:

```
blobUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(Blob);
```

and add download link:

```
<a href="'+ blobUrl +'" download="filename.pdf">
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF to create PDF. Here example: https://parall.ax/products/jspdf

For MS Word, try https://github.com/MrRio/DOCX.js. But I don't think you can conver base64 to docx